# How to build a street gradient with a curve (Avoiding rotation)

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms

i'm new. I want to build a street, which follows a curve. The street has a 270° curve with gradient.
Here a picture to illustrate it:
[image]

The picture show also my problem. The street rotates on the second end.

How can i avoid this effect?

Comment: Realize though, that a road must have camber while it is both changing direction and altitude. In other words, it can only be laterally level over a section in which it's direction doesn't change no matter how short that section is.

Comment: Also note, not even dragging vertices by hand will change the fact that it is a topological impossibility to create a ribbon that remains laterally level while it is climbing and changing direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *twist* the curve points using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> :

[image]

Or you can use the *Z up* curve option :

[image]

Comment: You can also adjust the twist at each control point using the Mean Tilt value in the Transforms panel.